# How can I install gscam in ros fuerte

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I install gscam for capturing videos from my webcam in ros fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60673/how-can-i-install-gscam-in-ros-fuerte/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-brown-perception`.

`gscam` is part of the brown_perception stack.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-04-15**:
while i run this I got the following error message       Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-brown-perception

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-04-15**:
Maybe try 'sudo apt-get update' first? I must say, I'm not an expert in these things but I got it installed in Groovy this way.

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-04-15**:
update I done. But still have this problem.  But on electric it installed ok. But on fuerte and groovy it produces the same error

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-04-15**:
Well, then the problem seems to be fuerte specific. I can't help you there, I'm afraid.

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-04-15**:
but don't able to install on groovy too

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-04-15**:
Did you install ROS using apt-get? What do you find if you do 'apt-cache search ros fuerte brown'?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
Are you on Oneiric?  The brown_perception stack is not building for oneiric under fuerte: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html